# populate embedded document on mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working with nodeJs and mongoose and I want to populate a sub-document

This is my main model

```
var postSchema = require('./post.js');
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postSchema: [postSchema]
});

var blog = mongoose.model('blog', blogSchema);

module.exports = blog;
```

this is the post sub-document

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rol: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var post = mongoose.model('post', post);

module.exports = post;
```

And I want to add several 'post' inside the 'blog' schema, but I don't know how, I tried populating it by I'm now doing it properly! I read about 'populate' on mongoose but I'm not understanding it at all, can someone explain it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Where is your code for how you are trying to add the sub documents?

Comment: `postSchema: [postSchema]` is [*Embedded* Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html). You can only [populate a *referenced* document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Those two links explain the difference in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arrays of external Eschemas in mongoose. You must define them in the same file, or just save the array of _id´s and create a collection appart.

Check the mongoose docs. They talk about that:     http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var blogPost = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rol: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var blog = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postList: [blogPost]
});

mongoose.model('blog', blogSchema);

module.exports = blog;



var Blog = mongoose.model('blog');

// create a blog post
var theBlog = new Blog();

// create a comment
theBlog.postList.push({ title: 'My comment' });

theBlog.postList.save(function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Success!');
});
```

Hope it may help you